# Styling for a facebook-like wall with wall posts

Tags: jquery, html, css

For the system that I'm currently working on, it needs to have a very similar look-n-feel to facebook's wall page for each user. This is how each post *should* look:

[image]

A checkbox, Avatar + name, a WC id, categories (user defined), actual text of the post, and a 'link bar' with *agree*, *comment* etc., (different for each type of post)

[image]

However with the styles/layouts that I've been playing with for quite a while, I've been unable to get it to look 'right'. Here is how it lands up looking like (The outer border is only for illustration purposes. For some reason an overlap happens with the unordered list and the post button. Screenshot on Chrome).

Here is the CSS:

```
.listOfPosts{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}

.post {
    display:block;
    margin-right:35px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:3px;
}

.avatarColumn {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
}

.avatarColumn a:link, .avatarColumn .authorName a:link {
    padding:2px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.postDetails, .categorizationDetails, .actionsNavBar {
    list-style-type:none;   
}

.postDetails li {
    display:block;
}

.categorizationDetails li, .actionsNavBar li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

.actionsNavBar li a {
    padding:2px;
}

.wcid {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
}

.category {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-right:1px;
}
```

and here is the HTML that I'm trying to style. It need not be represented this way but I *thought* of presenting it as such. Suggestions are more than welcome if it should be *structured* differently :) (div 'main' is 560px in width and is the center column in a 3 column layout)

```
 <div id="main">
          <div id="postArea">
              <form action="/ezbay/wincondition" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="winconditionform">
                <textarea name="wincondition" id="wincondition"></textarea>
                <button id="postwincondition" type="submit">Post</button>
            </form>

          </div>


        <ul class="listOfPosts">

            <li class="post">
                <div class="avatarColumn">
                    <a href="#"><img src="defaultavatar.gif" width="86" height="51" /></a>
                    <div class="authorName"><a href="#">Nupul</a></div>
                </div>            
                <div class="postDetailsContainer">
                    <ul class="postDetails">

                        <li>
                            <ul class="categorizationDetails">                    
                                <li class="wcid">WC1</li>

                                <li class="category">FR</li>
                                <li class="category">Interface</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>The posts should be similar in look and feel to that of facebook style wall posts, with the necessary indentation for Issues/options</li>

                        <li>
                            <ul class="actionsNavBar">
                                <li><a href="#" class="actionNavBarLink">Agree</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="actionNavBarLink">Comment</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="actionNavBarLink">Raise Issue/Concern/Risk</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
   </div>
```

Any ideas on how to get it 'right' :) For now I didn't add the checkbox nor the 'time elapsed since post' but I guess that shouldn't be difficult once I get the layout right. JQuery-based solutions are fine too :)

Thanks!

PS: Here's the code for the textarea and the button just in case:

```
textarea#wincondition {
    min-width:496px;
    max-width:496px;
    min-height:100px;
    resize:none;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#999;
    overflow:hidden;

}

button#postwincondition {
    float:right;
    margin-top:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #3B5998;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    color:#FFF;
    width:70px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nupul, have you reset your CSS? By default most browsers applies margin, padding and other CSS properties on elements. This has to be countered if you want pixel perfection cross browser. :)

Comment: @Jonas: I'm not sure how to even do that :) If I've accidentally reset it how do I "un-reset" it (for lack of a better word)?

Comment: ^^ I'm sure this is something slightly less complicated. Does clearing the float not resolve this issue? If not then let me know and we can try something else.

Comment: you can read about css reset here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ . The jist is that it's easier to un-reset than not reset. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue may be caused by not clearing your floating element.

Add new css style:

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

And then add a new div with the class "clear" as the last item within your post. This should hopefully resolve your issue:

```
<li class="post">
    <div class="avatarColumn">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="postDetailsContainer">
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: This part DID fix the problem of ul overlapping with the post button! Thanks a ton! But just doing a clear:both on ul didn't seem to work (without the div). Any ideas why?

Comment: To follow up, I also tried the idea of the *clear* div after li.categorization and it seemed to work fine. I deleted it later and tried a few tricks and it seemed to work! I've posted it as an answer, but there is something still missing in the *look*

Comment: @Nupul - I'm not sure why the clear on the ul did not work. Did you do it inline or as part of a class? The purpose of clear is to remove a float (left, right or both), which results in the cleared element sitting below the previous floating element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final output that I get after **quite** a bit of tweaking and dunking dreamweaver over Aptana :) (only for easy/quick shortcuts for indenting/formatting code to facilitate readability)

[image]

The ul.listOfPosts is preceded by a div.clear as suggested by @MyHeadHurts. Just applying a margin on ul and clear:both didn't seem to work. I also did that for the li.categorization class and removed it later when I tweaked the layout yet again!

Here's the final CSS that seems to work for now:

```
.listOfPosts {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .post {
        display:block;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-top:10px;
        border-top-style:solid;
        border-top-color:#999;
        border-top-width:1px;
    }
    .postContainer {
        width:540px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    .avatarColumn {
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        margin-right:2px;
        width:80px;
    }
    .avatarColumn .authorName {
        margin-top:10px;
        width:inherit;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .avatarColumn a:link, .avatarColumn .authorName a:link {
        padding:2px;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .avatarColumn a:link {
        width: inherit;
        height:50px;
        padding:1px;
    }
    .avatarColumn img {
        width:70px;
        height:50px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        border:none;
    }
    .postDetailsContainer {
        float:left;
        width:450px;
    }
    .postDetails, .postDetails .categorizationDetails, .postDetails .actionsNavBar {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .postDetails li {
        display:block;
    }
    .postDetails .categorizationDetails li, .postDetails .actionsNavBar li {
        display:inline;
        float:left;
    }
    .postDetails .actionsNavBar li a {
        margin-left:2px;
        margin-right:2px;
        padding:2px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .postDetails .actionsNavBar li a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .postDetails .wcid {
        font-weight:bold;
        color:black;
        margin-right:3px;
    }
    .categorizationDetails .category {
        background-color:red;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-left:2px;
        margin-right:2px;
    }
    .postDetails .postData {
        margin-top:4px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
    span.dotSeparator {
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
        top:-30%;
        left:-1px;
    }
```

The only extra thing is the postContainer which is just a wrapper dive for the entire 'post' so as to enable centering and added a 'dotSeparator' for the 'links' at the bottom.

To be honest I really don't know what seemed to 'fix' the issue. I did reorganize the CSS code for better 'inheritance' style readability and added a clear class and a postContainer div. Can someone spot a major difference? :)

Comment: Have you tried putting multiple posts on your page yet? I have tried it now and you get a cascading effect. You generally need to clear any floats you have applied - so to fix this you would add clear:both to your #post id.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: Yup! Face that problem. Did a clear:both and the *top borders* of each of the posts seems to line up well. But no amount of margin/padding less than 100px seems to show up for spacing between posts!!! Very strange. I admit I'm not a pro with div based layouts and the corresponding css, but it's kinda tricky to understand this type of behavior. W3Schools only helps so much... :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: Haaaa! I guess I understood your comment after writing mine: "you must clear **any floats** you have applied..." I did a clear as you suggested above just before </li> and it seems to work! Okay so to understand this clearly: It doesn't matter if the n-th level nested div was a float, you still must clear it when operating outside the 'root level' (so to speak, for that component/layer e.g.: .post = root and .avatarColumn = nested in root). Why can't this be done by adding a clear:both to .post itself? I tried that and doesn't seem to work? Why the need for a special 'clear div'?

Comment: You will be able to use clear:both in the #post div, and that should clear the float - it worked when I tried it with your code. The best way to think about clear is to decide - do I want the next item to float after this one. It not, then apply a clear on the next item OR use the clear div. Don't ever leave a float uncleared or you will just run into trouble later on. Also, I'm not sure if you know, but you can apply multiple classes in one div, for example you could do the following <div class="post clear"></div>. This would work the same as adding clear to that css class.